# Контуры изображения

Tags: javascript

Есть идеи, как сделать [вот такое](http://bazalt.ru/), а точнее менюшку (не активное - просто контур). Даны только изображения (оружия). Проблема в том, как нарисовать контур. Может, кто-то знает библиотеку подходящую или идейку подкинет.

Answer (score 1):

[svg?](https://www.google.com.ua/search?site=&source=hp&q=svg&oq=svg&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.613.1536.0.1741.3.3.0.0.0.0.117.320.1j2.3.0....0...1c.1.54.hp..0.3.318.o19_H95NapQ)

> SVG (от англ. Scalable Vector Graphics — масштабируемая векторная графика) — язык разметки масштабируемой векторной графики, созданный Консорциумом Всемирной паутины (W3C) и входящий в подмножество расширяемого языка разметки XML, предназначен для описания двумерной векторной и смешанной векторно/растровой графики в формате XML. Поддерживает как неподвижную, так и анимированную интерактивную графику — или, в иных терминах, декларативную и скриптовую.

На сайте, что вы привели в качестве примера, используется тег [area](http://htmlbook.ru/html/area) (посмотрите исходники страницы, там где куча чисел).

Comment: Проблема в том, чтобы сделать контур изображения, имея только изображение в формате png, на сайте, что я привел в пример, используют просто бекраунд изображение с готовыми нарисованными контурами, а мне нужно динамически контур сделать.

Comment: [Вряд ли выйдет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690444/css-border-on-png-image-with-transparent-parts). Да и тянуть целую картинку ради контура.